# Slack API forcefully overrides file extension with incorrect one

Tags: slack-api

I'm using a Slack bot to upload a file via Slack API. File format is .csv, extension is .csv and I specify that `filetype=csv`. Yet, Slack API (`file.upload`) response tells me that Slack accepted my file as a Python file and forcefully appended a `.py` extension to it. Now every time anyone downloads that file, it's .csv file with a .py extension.

My guess is that it sees the `"""` and immediately thinks "oh, I know! It's a python-ish comment! it must be a Python file, regardless of what the requester says - I know better! I'll rename that file for him!"

Repro:

file (it was a valid csv, I've just trimmed its contents down)

```
/tmp/playground/slack_py_repro$ cat test_run_6588_errors_summary_by-action_report.csv
HTTP Status-Code=504 (Gateway Time-out) for ""{URL}"""
HTTP Status-Code=504 (Gateway Time-out) for ""{URL}"""
```

```
/tmp/playground/slack_py_repro$ curl -sLk -F file=@test_run_6588_errors_summary_by-action_report.csv -F "filename=test_run_6588_errors_summary_by-action_report.csv" -F "filetype=csv" -F "channels=${CHANNEL}" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" https://slack.com/api/files.upload | jq
{
  "ok": true,
  "file": {
    "id": "<HIDDEN>",
    "created": 1655497834,
    "timestamp": 1655497834,
    "name": "test_run_6588_errors_summary_by-action_report.csv.py",
    "title": "test run 6588 errors summary by-action report.csv",
    "mimetype": "text/plain",
    "filetype": "python",
    "pretty_type": "Python",
    "editable": true,
    "size": 110,
    "mode": "snippet",
    "is_external": false,
    "external_type": "",
    "is_public": false,
/* ... */
  }
}
```

FWIW I think it also poses a security risk. I may upload a malicious Python file with a .csv extension, on the Slack web it'll say it's a .csv file, but when downloaded it'll become a .csv.py and an inattentive user will open it up expecting to see a spreadsheet. Of course, a Python runtime will kick in and it's a ggwp for that poor lad's computer/data/network.

What am I doing wrong? How do I tell the Slack API to keep its fingers away from my files' extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reached out to Slack support. Turns out, that no matter what you do, Slack will try to auto-guess the uploaded file type itself. As the support rep put it, Slack must ensure that it can read and understand the file contents. When I addressed this justification as an alarming one (due to security reasons), I was explained that Slack needs to understand file contents in order to generate a preview for it (although it does not work for some files, e.g. for .xls the preview generation is explicitly disabled). The `filetype` hint does not do much. And in this particular case, Slack recognizes the `"""` as Python's multiline comment opening/closing sequence.

As the support rep explained, this bug is not trivial to fix and might take some time. Why can't they reuse the same mechanism in the REST-api that's being successfully used in the web-api - I don't know. And, frankly, it's not my product to worry about such decisions.